# RecyclerView with dynamic row content is not scrollable to the end of it

Tags: android

It's been two days that I'm trying to figure out what should I do and I've searched and searched an nothing helped me, so here I am:

I have a RecyclerView that its rows have two part. First part is a layout with static contents and second part is a LinearLayout with its height set to WRAP_CONTENT that its content are suppose to be dynamic. So for the dynamic part I'll create its content based on a JSON and create some views an add them to that. So everything works perfectly unless it seems that the height of RecyclerView is computed before the dynamic contents are added. So the result will be a RecyclerView that is not scrollable to its end. I have tested fixing RecyclerView height with a constant big number and all the content will be visible.

Layout of static part:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="@dimen/main_items_padding">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/icon_gap_main"
        android:background="@drawable/main_items_back">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/main_items_icon_size"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dynamic_content"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout of dynamic part that will be add to "dynamic_content" LinearLayout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_gap_main"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Code"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the RecyclerAdapter is:

```
public class DynamicContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DynamicContentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private static String items;
    private JSONObject itemsObjects;
    private ArrayList<String> fields;
    private ArrayList<String> fa_fields;
    public RecyclerView reference;

    public DynamicContentAdapter(Context mContext, RecyclerView reference) throws JSONException {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.reference = reference;
        items = "{\"names\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"],\"USSD\":[\"*1#\",\"*2#\",\"*3#\",\"*4#\",\"*2#\",\"*3#\",\"*4#\",\"*2#\",\"*3#\",\"*4#\"],\"Price\":[\"1000\",\"2000\",\"3000\",\"4000\",\"2000\",\"3000\",\"4000\",\"2000\",\"3000\",\"4000\"],\"fields\":[\"names\",\"price\"],\"fa_fields\":[\"Names\",\"Price\"]}";
        itemsObjects = new JSONObject(items);
        fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fa_fields = new ArrayList<>();
        extractFields();
        extractFaFields();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public LinearLayout dynamicContent;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            dynamicContent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_content);
        }
    }

    private void extractFields() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = itemsObjects.getJSONArray("fields");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            fields.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
        }
    }

    private void extractFaFields() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = itemsObjects.getJSONArray("fa_fields");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            fa_fields.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LinearLayout content;
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.dynamic_content_item, parent, false);
        content = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_content);

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
            View dynamic =     LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dynamic_content_inside_layout, parent, false);
            dynamic.setTag(i);
            content.addView(dynamic);
        }
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < fields.size(); iterator++) {
            TextView name, title;
            name = (TextView)     holder.dynamicContent.findViewWithTag(iterator).findViewById(R.id.name);
            title = (TextView)     holder.dynamicContent.findViewWithTag(iterator).findViewById(R.id.title);
            name.setText(fa_fields.get(iterator));
            try {
                    title.setText(itemsObjects.getJSONArray(fields.get(iterator)).getString(position    ));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        try {
            return itemsObjects.getJSONArray(fields.get(0)).length();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your layout code.

Comment: Post the RecyclerView code too

Comment: I've posted what you asked. Thanks for your attention.